# Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/.../plugins/org.jboss.tools.jst.web_3.5.0.Final-v20130717-0309-B75.jar!/catalog/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd)

Tags: xml, jsf, jsf-2, faces-config, jboss-tools

I make in JSF Project in eclipse and The  file **faces-config.xml** give an error

```
Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/D:/eclips/eclipse k/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jst.web_3.5.0.Final-v20130717-0309-B75.jar!/catalog/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd).
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

when I remove the following line, error indication vanish in **faces-config.xml**

```
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd
```

Update me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Is your  jars JSF version 2.2. ?

Comment: @erencan yes!  version="2.2" showing above in faces-config.xml

Comment: i am asking for jar versions.

Comment: @erencan yes! `JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.0)\mojarra-2.2.0-FCS\lib\javax.faces.jar`

Comment: Try the current development release of JBoss Tools: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/kepler/

Comment: I am using Kepler @BalusC

Comment: I know. Have you tried the current development release of JBoss Tools as asked in previous comment?

Comment: Base on your recommendation I refer your previous comment but `Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/D:/eclips/eclipse k/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jst.web_3.5.1.Alpha1-v20130906-1546-B80.jar!/catalog/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd)` again error ! :( @BalusC

Comment: Well, report it to JBoss Tools guys: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE In the meanwhile, just ignore the error. The code should work and run just fine.

Comment: OK! To remove error I put semi colon (;) between two location (xsi:schemaLocation) such as `xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee; http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"` now there is no any error ! @BalusC

Answer (score 11):

You specified `http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee` twice, so remove one.

Comment: The faces-config.xml of JSF 2.2 is created with a duplicated namespace. So the above answer is actually correct. Remove the first occurrence of 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 5):

Disabling caching of XSD files fixed the issues for me - with Eclipse Neon, the relevant option is at Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections->Cache->Disable Caching. Check that box, then clean and build.  I think in my case what happened is I tried to rebuild while on a wifi with no internet connection, Eclipse tried to validate those files and couldn't, and decided to show this type of error.

Comment: I didn't have to disable caching, but clearing out the current Cached entries resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me, removing the duplicate namespace had an unpleasant side effect of disabling content assist when editing faces-config.xml.

These headers with "duplicate" namespaces are specified everywhere like that, the faces-config one in particular is mentioned in the JSF specification. Even the W3C XML Schema specification features [a similar example](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#schema-loc).

So it seems that the header in question is correct. Installing the latest updates for Eclipse and JBoss tools solved this problem for me.

It may be related to these JBoss Tools issues: [JBIDE-14439](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-14439), [JBIDE-15605](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-15605).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options(i only found these.. haha):

1 - You specified http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee twice, so remove one.(by Shukti)

2- If you're getting some erros like "cvc-complex-type..." just put `<from-view-id>something here </from-view-id>` in navigation-rules for each line with error. (the error will disapear, but, i can't ensure it will work for you).

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in `weblogic.xml` file, so I removed space in `<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">` and then `clean build`. It is working fine for me.